# Learning SQL, trying to find out why my FK isn't working

Tags: sql, oracle

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Engineers
(
    EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Lastname varchar(40),
    Firstname varchar(25),
    Email varchar(60),
    Graddate varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Faculty
(
    FID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Lastname varchar(40),
    Firstname varchar(25),
    Email varchar(60),
    Hiredate varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Classes
(
    CID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Subject varchar(12),
    Catalognbr INT,
    Title varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollments
(
    EnID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EngineerID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(EngineerID) REFERENCES Engineers(EID),
    FacultyID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(FacultyID) REFERENCES Faculty(FID),
    ClassID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ClassID) REFERENCES Classes(CID)
);
```

Here is one snip of the data I'm inserting:

```
INSERT INTO Engineers(EID, Lastname, Firstname, Email, Graddate)
VALUES(1, 'Bloober', 'Martha', 'BlooberBoogers@gmail.com', '10/29/2022');

INSERT INTO Faculty(FID, Lastname, Firstname, Email, Hiredate)
Values(1, 'Hickory', 'Bob', 'IamMrClean@gmail.com', '10/30/1995');

INSERT INTO Classes(CID, Subject, Catalognbr, Title)
Values(1, 'SDEV', '350', 'Database Security');

INSERT INTO ClassEnrollments(EnID, EngineerID, FacultyID, ClassID)
Values(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Now everything runs through but my insert into classenrollments isn't working, I'm assuming I am inserting my foreign keys wrong. But am unsure, I have been looking a bit online but haven't seen anything that I have done so far. Any suggestions would be great.

Here is my error message:

> Error starting at line : 84 in command -
> INSERT INTO ClassEnrollments(EnID, EID, FID, CID)
> Values(1, 1, 1, 1)
> Error at Command Line : 84 Column : 46
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CID": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: The question may be answered as it is asked (like "use correct column names" or "perform multitable insert"), but I doubt it's what you really want. Please clarify how you would process the enrollment for already existing class: for ex, you want to insert a new attendee `(2, 'Jon', 'Doe', date '1980-01-01')` for class `350`. What will be an input? Should it be done in a single process (engineer creation and enrollment creation) or separate processes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct column names

```
INSERT INTO ClassEnrollments(EnID, EngineerID, FacultyID, ClassID)
Values(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

What you want according to your comments is:

```
SELECT e.Firstname AS engineerFirstname, e.Lastname as engineerLastname, 
       f.Firstname AS facultyFirstname, f.Lastname as facultyLastname, 
       c.Title AS ClassTitle
From ClassEnrollments ce
INNER JOIN Engineers e ON e.EID = ce.EngineerID  
INNER JOIN Faculty f ON f.FID = ce.FacultyID 
INNER JOIN Classes c ON c.CID = ce.ClassID
```

Comment: I actually just tried that, but it doesn't get the data from the pks. The Classenrollments table just says: 1,1,1,1.

Comment: Yes, of course. To get the data related to that you need to JOIN the tables. Please take a SQL tutorial. You seem to be new to SQL.

Comment: @fasterjake the first list after `insert into tablename` represents the columns of that table that you wish to insert into. The second list specifies the corresponding values to be inserted.

Comment: 'INSERT INTO ClassEnrollments(EnID, EngineerID, FacultyID, ClassID)
Select EnID,Engineers.EID, Faculty.FID, Classes.CID
FROM ClassEnrollments, Engineers, Faculty, Classes
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Engineers.EID = ClassEnrollments.EngineerID
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Faculty.FID = ClassEnrollments.FacultyID
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Classes.CID = ClassEnrollments.ClassID;
'

Comment: SELECT ENID,EID, FID, CID
From ClassEnrollments, Engineers, Faculty, Classes
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Engineers.EID = ClassEnrollments.EID
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Faculty.FID = ClassEnrollments.FID
INNER JOIN ClassEnrollments ON Classes.CID = ClassEnrollments.CID



Am I heading in the right direction, stuck on this error code.

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ENGINEERS"."EID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Actually you are not getting close. But I updated the anwer.